# Batch, replace a delay expansion string with delay expansion parameters

Tags: batch-file, replace, cmd, window

basically I am just using this piece to replace a string in my var, but I can't get nested delay expansion to work correctly. Is this even possible?

```
set replace=!replace:!search!=!replaceVal!!
```

I know what going on when it is getting executed. It stops at after the first complete set which would be `set replace=!replace:!` and then it attempts to execute the last part, but is there a way to escape them so it will properly get my outcome?

Answer (score 5):

I think the most secure way is the following:

```
for /F "delims=" %%S in (^""!search!"^") do (
    for /F "delims=" %%R in (^""!replaceVal!"^") do (
        set "replace=!replace:%%~S=%%~R!"
    )
)
```

So the only remaining restrictions are those that apply for the sub-string replacement syntax anyway.

---

An even simpler yet equally safe approach  is this:

```
for /F "delims=" %%S in (^""!search!=!replaceVal!"^") do (
    set "replace=!replace:%%~S!"
)
```

As you can see there is even no need to keep search and replace strings separated until the end.

Comment: At last, a correct answer that **works**.

Answer (score 2):

[example]

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

SET "search=aaa"
SET "replace=jjj"
IF DEFINED search (
 SET "replace=xxxbbbyyybbbhhh"
 SET "search=bbb"
 SET "replaceval=kkk"
 SET REPLACE
 ECHO after...
 CALL SET "replace=%%replace:!search!=!replaceval!%%"
 SET replace
)

GOTO :EOF
```

Comment: The issue is my search and replace values are based on value that will be get from the script execution. The set commands are in a block.

Comment: So? The example shows that the values for `search`, `replaceval` and `replace` are set within a block. Note that with the first `set replace` (which shows the value of each variable starting `replace`) the values are neither `aaa` nor `jjj`. They have been replaced by values assigned within the block. The `after` situation shows after-the-replacement, still no `aaa` or `jjj` in sight, and the value assigned within the block `xxxbbbyyybbbhhh` has had the string assigned within the block `bbb` replaced by the replaceval assigned within the block `kkk`.

Answer (score 1):

This works as long as the `search` and `replace` values have not spaces:

```
for /F "tokens=1,2" %%a in ("!search! !replaceVal!") do set replace=!replace:%%a=%%b!
```

If these variables have spaces, just insert an appropriate delimiter:

```
for /F "tokens=1,2 delims==" %%a in ("!search!=!replaceVal!") do set replace=!replace:%%a=%%b!
```